# Capistrano 3 setfacl failing

Tags: php, laravel, capistrano3

I am getting this command using a pretty vanilla staging.rb file:

`/usr/bin/env setfacl -m u:www-data:rwx,u:s272shop:rwx /home/s272shop/deployment/releases/20140204030518/app/storage`

The problem is that `www-data` doesn't exist in any of my deployment files, nor does that user exist on my server, so it fails. I don't know how to set it.

When I run `cap staging deploy --trace`, it happens in the `deploy:set_permissions:acl`. I don't call that explicitly. Can I call something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After searching in the Ruby Gems directory I found this in the file-permissions readme.

`set :file_permissions_users, ["www-data"]`

I added that to my deploy.rb and changed it to my user... and it worked like a charm.